# How to load sub index.html page to localhost in cordova ios

Tags: ios

I am working on an ios project with cordova wkwebkit.
Of course, I know that cordova recommends spa.
In the case of the main index.html file, the page was opened on localhost as shown below in config.xml.

```
   <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
        <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
    </platform>
```

Then you can see that the result of checking in Chrome developer mode is applied successfully.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otpfc.png)

But in the case of the sub index.html file, I don't know how to load it on localhost.
solution is required.

Currently, we are loading the sub index.html file with the file protocol.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwUH3.png)

file path:
(main) index.html path : www/index.html
(sub) index.html path : www/world/wikitude_AR/inedex.html

version:
cordova  - 11
cordova ios - 6.2

Comment: Edit first line sentence
wkwebkit => wkwebview

Comment: You can edit your own question as needed.